# How do I create a conditional WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, where-clause

I need to have a conditional where clause that operates as so:

```
Select *
From Table
If (@booleanResult)
Begin
  Where Column1 = 'value1'
End
Else
Begin
  Where column1 = 'value1' and column2 = 'value2'
End
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Could you just do the following?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Table
WHERE
    (@booleanResult = 1
    AND Column1 = 'value1')
OR
    (@booleanResult = 0
    AND Column1 = 'value1'
    AND Column2 = 'value2')
```

Comment: Won't this give me both sides of the OR in my result?

Comment: I came back to this and changed the accepted answer. After looking back over it, what I wanted wasn't what I had really conveyed in the question. Siva answered more what I wanted, but you accurately answered what was asked. Sorry about that - this is the fair way to go about it.

Comment: Keep in mind that short circuiting doesn't always work as you expect in SQL.  It's left to the db vendor to decide how to evaluate an expression.

Comment: Just a thank you @diaho as this helped me just now to have a conditional where allowing either evaluation of an ID = 1 OR ID in (1,2,3,4) depending if the user passed anything into the stored proc :).

Answer (score 16):

You can group conditions easily in a `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE
   (@BooleanResult=1 AND Column1 = 'value1')
OR
   (@BooleanResult=0 AND Column1 = 'value1' AND column2 = 'value2')
```

Comment: Won't this give me both sides of the OR in my result?

Comment: @Yatrix yes it will.  But you'll never match BOTH since you are checking `@Booleanresult` and it can't be both `1` and `0`.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the script in question, it seems that you need the condition for `Column1` irrespective of whether the variable `@booleanResult` is set to true or false. So, I have added that condition to the `WHERE` clause and in the remaining condition checks whether the variable is set to **1** (*true*) or if it is set to **0** (*false*) then it will also check for the condition on `Column2`.

This is just one more way of achieving this.

#### Create and insert script:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    Column1 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  , Column2 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO MyTable (Column1, Column2) VALUES
  ('value1', ''),
  ('',       'value2'),
  ('value1', 'value2');
```

#### Script when bit variable is set to 1 (true):

```
DECLARE @booleanResult BIT
SET @booleanResult = 1

SELECT      *
FROM        MyTable
WHERE       Column1 = 'value1'
AND         (        @booleanResult = 1
                OR  (@booleanResult = 0 AND Column2 = 'value2')
            );
```

*Output*:

```
COLUMN1 COLUMN2
------- -------
value1  
value1  value2
```

#### Script when bit variable is set to 0 (false):

```
DECLARE @booleanResult BIT
SET @booleanResult = 0

SELECT      *
FROM        MyTable
WHERE       Column1 = 'value1'
AND         (        @booleanResult = 1
                OR  (@booleanResult = 0 AND Column2 = 'value2')
            );
```

*Output*:

```
COLUMN1 COLUMN2
------- -------
value1  value2
```

#### Demo:

[**Click here to view the demo in SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5834a/5)

Comment: I just thought yours was the most complete example and most helpful to me, personally. Up votes for all, but there can be only one (accepted)!

Comment: I changed my accepted answer. What you gave me was exactly what I was looking for, but to be fair, as you stated, what they gave me was what I asked for. I just didn't ask the best question. At this point, I can't exactly remember what the question I really wanted was. =)

Answer (score 2):

To provide a shorter answer:

```
Select *
From Table
Where Column1 = 'value1' and
      coalesce(column2, '') = (case when @BooleanResults = 0 
                                    then 'value1' 
                                    else coalesce( column2, '')
                               end)
```

Comment: Are you just making up syntax?  What RDBMS is that valid for?

Comment: Oops, I had left in some extraneous characters.  The rest of the syntax is standard SQL and should be understood by any databse that accepts local variables starting with a "@".

Comment: The answer is shorter, but the code is not. However, +1 for avoiding the _short circuiting_, which makes it useful for more SQL flavors.

Answer (score 0):

Query 1: if the @CompanyID is set to -1 then all records are selected

Query 2: if the @CompanyID is set to 10 or 11 or 12, only those records are selected where the companyid=@CompanyID

```
Declare @CompanyID int
Set @CompanyID = -1
```

```
select * from sales 
where  1=IIF(@CompanyID =-1, 1, IIF(CompanyID =@CompanyID,1,0))
```

```
Set @CompanyID = 10
select * from sales 
where  1=IIF(@CompanyID =-1, 1, IIF(CompanyID =@CompanyID,1,0))
```