# How to convert complex block condition in to MSSQL procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have some checkbox(Condition Filter) which user can tick select filter condition

for example:

```
CheckBox 1 : OrderNumber
CheckBox 2 : Driver
CheckBox 3 : Code
...
```

and pass into stored procedure - some thing like this :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DailyBatchSummaryReport_NoGroup]
@FromDatePara Datetime,
@ToDatePara Datetime,
@SeleRecipe nvarchar(max),
@SeleOrder nvarchar(max),
@SeleCustomer nvarchar(max),
@SeleSite nvarchar(max),
@SeleTruck nvarchar(max),
@SeleDriver nvarchar(max),
AS
BEGIN
```

// Stuck at this point

I want to write one procedure can handle muti-case of user selection, I have idea with string builder and pass in to WHERE clause, but SQLSERVER not accept this (It accept boolean parameter)

could someone help me. Thanks you.

Comment: Can you give the clear information on what you want and provide sample data that may help us to give the correct answer.

Comment: you can use conditional where clause as described in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521677/how-do-i-create-a-conditional-where-clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it as follows

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DailyBatchSummaryReport_NoGroup]
@FromDatePara Datetime,
@ToDatePara Datetime,
@SeleRecipe nvarchar(max),
@SeleOrder nvarchar(max),
@SeleCustomer nvarchar(max),
@SeleSite nvarchar(max),
@SeleTruck nvarchar(max),
@SeleDriver nvarchar(max),
AS
BEGIN
```

Pass @SeleOrder , @SeleCustomer values as 0 for unchecked and 1 for checkbox checked

```
select * from
yourtable
where 
OrderNumber= CASE WHEN @SeleOrder = '0' THEN OrderNumber ELSE @SeleOrder END
AND
CUSTOMER= CASE WHEN @SeleCustomer = '0' THEN CUSTOMER ELSE @SeleCustomer END
AND
Driver= CASE WHEN @SeleDriver = '0' THEN Driver ELSE @SeleDriver END
```

Make sure you pass default value as 0. Here you have choose datatype as nvarchar(max) so I have written '0' else you can write 0 if you pass just int value. or you can set default value as 0

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DailyBatchSummaryReport_NoGroup]
    @FromDatePara Datetime,
    @ToDatePara Datetime,
    @SeleRecipe int  = 0,
    @SeleOrder int  = 0,
    @SeleCustomer int  = 0,
    @SeleSite int  = 0,
    @SeleTruck int  = 0,
    @SeleDriver int  = 0,
    AS
    BEGIN
```

choose the logic as per your coding convenience. but above method will work

Comment: Thanks for your great. This method work expected. Hope this answer can help some one else to solve their problems similar me.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try somthing like this in where condition:-

If user selects check box then pass respective value or pass null.

So your where condition can be like

```
Where
(Colname1 = @Paramenter1 or @Paramenter1 is null)
and 
(Colname2 = @Paramenter2 or @Paramenter2 is null)
```

.... so on....

Comment: I will try your method and feedback ASAP. Thank for your answer