# Handle NULL Parameter in SQL Server Table Valued Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, parameters, null

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_roles(@userid varchar(36))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
        SELECT * 
        FROM user_roles
        WHERE userid = @userid
```

My function accepts a parameter `@userid` and returns roles that the user is assigned to from the `user_roles` table.

What if I want to return all records from the `user_roles` table if a `NULL` value for the parameter is passed? What would be the most elegant way to handle that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check parameter is null using `ISNULL` in this situation it will return userId  so it will return all roles as following :

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_roles(@userid varchar(36))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
select * from  user_roles
where userid = ISNULL(@userid,userid)
```

Comment: I want to return ALL records from that table if NULL parameter is passed.  What you suggest will return no records.

Comment: But the user wants to return *all* the rows. Also, adding the `ISNULL` would do nothing to chanbge the behaviour; nothing equals `NULL`, including `NULL`.

Comment: This is more elegant than the previous one

Answer (score 3):

Simply add it to the where clause with `or`:

```
select * 
from   user_roles
where  userid = @userid or @userid is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the least but just another option you can try this way also.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_roles (@userid VARCHAR(36))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN

SELECT *
FROM user_roles
WHERE @userid IS NULL
    OR (
        @userid IS NOT NULL
        AND userid = @userid
        )
```

[How do I create a conditional WHERE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521677/how-do-i-create-a-conditional-where-clause)